# Redisson: Is there a way to use different codec for classes in specific packages instead of the globally configured one?

Tags: java, caching, codec, redisson

In my current project, Redisson is used for caching many different classes using the JsonJacksonCodec. This works as intended but I want to have classes only in a certain package serialized using MsgPack instead while leaving the rest serialized as they already are.

From what I found, this is possible by either configuring the RObject (https://github.com/redisson/redisson/wiki/16.-FAQ#q-can-i-use-different-encoderdecoders-for-different-tasks) or by using CompositeCodec but in the first case, it seems to me I can still only supply one codec to redisson configuration and would need multiple instances configured differently to achieve my goal, while in the second case, the CompositeCodec is used for chaining several codecs together, one after another, instead of using different codecs for different classes. Unfortunately, both documentation and examples of advanced Redisson usage are minimal so I'm not sure if I'm right on any of these conclusions.

Is there an easy way to achieve this and what would be the best way to do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every redisson object could be supplied with own codec.

Code example for Map object:

```
RMap<String, String> map = redisson.getMap("myMap", new MyCodec());
```

Comment: This seems to do exactly what I wanted. I was looking in the Config class which has been the wrong place apparently. Thank you for the help!